# Theorem about coupling and independence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence, coupling

I am reading a [book of E. Rio](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-54323-8) and I found there a theorem (*without a proof*) about coupling. Please see below.

> **Theorem:** Let $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a sequence of random variables with values in some Polish space $X$. Assume that $(\Omega, \mathcal{T}, \mathbb{P})$ is rich enough to contain a random variable $U$ with uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$, independent of $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$. Let $\mathcal{F_0} = \sigma(\xi_i: i \le 0)$ and $\mathcal{G}_n = \sigma(\xi_i: i \ge n)$. Then one can construct a sequence $(\xi^*_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ with the same joint distribution as the initial sequence $(\xi_i )_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$, independent of $\mathcal{F}_0$ and measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-field generated by $U$ and $(\xi^*_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$, in such a way that, for any positive integer $n$,
> $$\mathbb{P}(\xi_k \neq \xi^*_k \text{for some } k \ge n \mid \mathcal{F_0}) = \text{esssup}(|\mathbb{P}(B \mid \mathcal{F_0})−\mathbb{P}(B)| \colon B \in \mathcal{G}_n).$$

**Question 1:** I am wondering what are the conditions these theorem to hold? Is my understanding correct that the only condition that $\mathcal{X} = (\Omega, \mathcal{T}, \mathbb{P})$ should be reach enough to contain a uniform r.v. independent of $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$?

**Question 2:** Could anyone provide some intuition about this condition (i.e., what does it mean, why is it crucial here, why uniform)? I would be grateful for any example where this condition doesn't hold.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Marco, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not meant to be a real answer. Probably only a proof of the theorem would clarify what's going on.

**Question 1**: I see another assumption of the theorem. The random variables $\xi_i$ are taking values on a *Polish space* $\mathcal{X}$.

**Question 2**: Why do we ask the random variable $U$ to be an $\mathrm{Unif}([0,1])$ independent of $(\xi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$?

### Fact:

If $U$ is $\mathrm{Unif}([0,1])$ and $F$ is some cumulative distribution function, then the random variable $F^{-1}(U)$ follows the distribution $F$, i.e. $$\mathbb{P}\bigl(F^{-1}(U)\le x\bigr) = F(x),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R},$$ where $F^{-1}$ is the generalized inverse function of $F$.

---

In other words, with such an $U$ one can define (on the same probability space) ***real-valued*** random variables with desired distributions. So, the existence of a random variable $U\sim\mathrm{Unif}([0,1])$ in a probability space guarantees the existence of ***real-valued*** random variables with any distribution. Furthermore, note that if $U$ is independent of another random variable $\xi$ with cdf $F_\xi$, then the random variable $\xi':=F_\xi^{-1}(U)$ follows the same distribution of $\xi$ and is also independent of $\xi$. Note the analogy with our theorem.

The theorem claims that there exists another sequence $(\xi'_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ with the same joint distribution of $(\xi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\dots$
It is clear that a constructive proof of our theorem needs to construct random variables ***taking values on the Polish space*** $\mathcal{X}$ with desired distributions.

Anyway, the statement of the theorem is general as it doesn't require the Polish space $\mathcal{X}$ to be $\mathbb{R}$, but I bet that its proof uses the existence of $U$ to define such a $(\xi'_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ in a constructive way.

And the second part of the question? What happens if our probability space is not rich enough?
Consider the probability space $\bigl(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\bigr)$ $$\Omega = \{T,H\},\\ \mathcal{F} = \bigl\{\emptyset, \{T\}, \{H\},  \Omega\bigr\}, \\ \mathbb{P}(\{T\}) = \frac{1}{3},\quad\mathbb{P}(\{H\}) = \frac{2}{3}.$$ Consider the random variable $\xi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ $$\xi(T)=0,\quad\xi(H)=1$$
This probability space is too poor, we cannot even find
a $\xi'$ with the same distribution and independent of $\xi$, as the only choice is $\xi'=\xi$, but clearly they are not independent.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Comment: I am also very interested in the techniques to prove the existence (or non-existence) of such a uniform random variable. @framago if you have something in mind I would be grateful if you could share.